# Comparing values from different rows in groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I would like to print each time inconsistency where the a start is different from the end from the previous row, grouped by the 'id' column. In the following data, the last row would be a case of inconsistency.

```
start,end,id
0,2,1
1,5,2
2,10,1
5,7,2
7,9,2
11,13,1
```

I have managed to do this using a for loop:

```py
def check_consistency(df):
    grouped_df = df.groupby('id')
    for key, group in grouped_df:
        df = pd.DataFrame()
        df['start'] = group['start'].iloc[1:]
        df['end'] = group['end'].shift().iloc[1:]
        consistent = df['start'] == df['end']
        if not all(consistent):
            print(key)
            print(df[consistent == False])
```

Is there a way to achieve the same goal without using a for loop and creating an auxiliar DataFrame?

**Edit**: following is the expected output.

DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'start': [0,1,2,5,7,11], 'end': [2,5,10,7,9,13], 'id': [1,2,1,2,2,1]})
```

Expected output:

```
1
   start   end
5     11  10.0
```

Comment: can you add the expected output to make it 100% clear?

Comment: Sure. I updated the question with the expected output.

Comment: good [mcve] :) upvote from me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, we sort by `id`.  Then make a mask comparing each `start` with previous row `end` and group by `id`.

For each group, the first entry of mask is defaulted to `True` since it has no previous row and is not to be selected for our extraction.

Finally, we select those rows with mask being False (`start` not equal to previous row `end`) by using `.loc` with the negation of the boolean mask.

```
df1 = df.sort_values('id', kind='mergesort')    # Merge Sort for stable sort to maintain sequence other than sort key
mask = (df1['start']
           .eq(df1['end'].shift())
           .groupby(df1['id']).transform(lambda x: [True] + x.iloc[1:].tolist())
       )
df1.loc[~mask]
```

Output:

```
   start     end  id
5     11      13   1
```